# SQL, Case with Like inside of the where

Tags: sql, database, datetime, case, ssms-2012

someone can help me please?
I have a field with this structure: 2,3,4,5,6,0,1
they are day of the week and I have to find when if today is the last delivery day of the week, the problem is this:

Example, today it's day 3 and with the following query I can select all the one that finish with the number 3 but if I have someone that has this structure: 3,0,1, or 3,1 or 3,0 I don't get them.

```
declare @today int
set @today=DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-2
print @today
select cast (cfv.value as VARCHAR)
from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
join CompanyFields cf on cf.companyFieldId=cfv.companyFieldId
where cf.name='NextDeliveryDates' and cfv.companyId in(
select cfv.companyId
from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
join Companies c on c.companyId=cfv.companyId
where cfv.value='Retailer' and c.status=1)
and (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR))
```

To fix it I tough to introduce a case, so my query will be this one:

```
declare @today int
set @today=DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-2
print @today
select cast (cfv.value as VARCHAR)
from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
join CompanyFields cf on cf.companyFieldId=cfv.companyFieldId
where cf.name='NextDeliveryDates' and cfv.companyId in(
select cfv.companyId
from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
join Companies c on c.companyId=cfv.companyId
where cfv.value='Retailer' and c.status=1)
and (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR))  and  case
        when (@today != 0 or @today!=1) 
        then (cfv.value not like '%,0' or cfv.value not like '%,1')
```

But in this case I receive this error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'not'.

I'm sure that I'm making some stupid mistake but I don't get it :S

Some help pls!
Thanks so much

Comment: Tag the dbms used, lots of product specific SQL there...

Comment: I mean tag the dbms product you're using. (E.g. SQL Server, or Oracle, or Sybase or something else.) Then your question will get better attention, and you will get better answers, faster!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a CASE statement should look something like this:

```
declare @today int
set @today=DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-2
print @today

select cfv.value
from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
join CompanyFields cf on cf.companyFieldId=cfv.companyFieldId
where cf.name='NextDeliveryDates' and cfv.companyId in(
select cfv.companyId
from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
join Companies c on c.companyId=cfv.companyId
where cfv.value='Retailer' and c.status=1)

and

CASE
    WHEN (@today !=0 or @today!=1) THEN
        (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' + cast    (@today as VARCHAR) 
        or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',0'
        or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',0,1'
        or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',1')
    ELSE
        (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' +  cast  (@today as VARCHAR))
END = 1
```

OR *************************************

```
 CASE
    WHEN ((@today !=0 or @today!=1) AND (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' + cast    (@today as VARCHAR) 
        or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',0'
        or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',0,1'
        or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',1'))
    THEN 1
    WHEN (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' +  cast  (@today as VARCHAR)) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

But it is true the expression (@today !=0 or @today!=1) is always true. Maybe you should find another meaningful condition

Comment: Hi Patricia, tks so much for the answer, no (@today !=0 or @today!=1) is not every time true because I declare my date as: set @today=DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-2 this because in the back I have a C# code that manage the date in a different way ;) I'm going to try your suggestion and I let you know ;)

Comment: Yes, it is always true. If you deny it, you will have something like this: today == 0 AND today == 1, which obviously it is always false. The problem is not the syntax of the CASE statement. The reason why you don't get the expected answer is because the logic is wrong.

Comment: Hi Patricia,yes you are correct I just try it :S and how could I do? but why today == 0 AND today == 1 is always fault? if I simulate this declare today int
set today=DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-5
print today ----- I have a today=0 so why should be false? how can I solve this issue? oh in any case I had to use the 2 option that you gave to me, the first one I don't know why was giving me problems. In any case I just posted a new answer with my current query and what is the problem when I simulate a 0 case

Comment: A value cannot be at the same time equal to 0 and equal to 1. Is either one of them, either none, but never both at the same time. For me the second suggestion I gave you it works in terms of syntax. Can you gave me the exact content of the tables and what you are trying to retrieve ?

Comment: Hi Patricia, yes sure... I'll post an answer with all the information, I'll call it UPDATE, but give me some minutes pls ;) tks so so much

Comment: Done :) Thanks so so much

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the CASE statement with the logical expression:

```
(((@today != 0 or @today!=1) AND (cfv.value not like '%,0' or cfv.value not like '%,1')) OR NOT (@today != 0 or @today!=1))
```

So your query will become:

```
declare @today int
set @today=DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-2
print @today
select cast (cfv.value as VARCHAR) from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
    join CompanyFields cf on cf.companyFieldId=cfv.companyFieldId
    where cf.name='NextDeliveryDates' and cfv.companyId in(
        select cfv.companyId
            from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
            join Companies c on c.companyId=cfv.companyId
            where cfv.value='Retailer' and c.status=1) 
            and (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value     like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)) 
            and  (((@today != 0 or @today!=1) AND (cfv.value not like '%,0' or cfv.value not like '%,1')) OR NOT (@today != 0 or @today!=1))
```

Comment: Admittedly you just copied this from the OP, but this part is always true; `(@today != 0 or @today!=1)` *(unless @today is NULL)*.  Also, the use of symbols `&&`, `||` should be replaced with the keywords `AND`, `OR`.

Comment: It still not working in every case, it's working if the value end for example with 3, the current day, but doesn't select when in the DB I have the values 3,0,1. I'm going to add an answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE for Patricia:

This is my table, it has just one row with this values that represent the last delivery day of a person, the problem is that they have this structure: 2,3,4,5,6,0,1

```
3,0,1
0,1
3,0
5,6
5,5
5
3
```

I need know if one of this person has last delivery day as today (0 and 1 are every time at the end but really they are not the last delivery day but the first and second).

I suppose that I have to create 2 separate case for 0 and 1 but I don't get them :S
This is what I actually have:

```
declare @today int
set @today=DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-2 /*-2 because the date are managed from a c# code so I need in this way to have the day in the format Monday=0, etc*/
print @today
select cfv.value
from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
join CompanyFields cf on cf.companyFieldId=cfv.companyFieldId
where cf.name='NextDeliveryDates' and cfv.companyId in(
select cfv.companyId
from CompanyFieldvalues cfv
join Companies c on c.companyId=cfv.companyId
where cfv.value='Retailer' and c.status=1)
and
 CASE
    WHEN ((@today !=0 or @today!=1) AND (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' + cast    (@today as VARCHAR) 
    or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',0'
    or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',0,1'
    or cfv.value like '%' + cast (@today as VARCHAR)+',1'))
    then 1
    WHEN (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' +  cast  (@today as VARCHAR)) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

in this moment as you say I have every time problem when it's day 0 or day 1.
If it's day 0 I have to select just the value=0, when is day 1 I have to select when the value=1 or value=0,1 so I think I need modify the second condition:

```
WHEN (cfv.value like '%,' + cast (@today as VARCHAR) or cfv.value like '%' +  cast  (@today as VARCHAR)) THEN 1
```

and create 2 different one isn't it?

Comment: You still have `(@today !=0 or @today!=1)` which is ***always*** TRUE...  If `@today = 0` then you have `(0 != 0) OR (0 != 1)` => `(FALSE) OR (TRUE)` => `TRUE`.  The only time it's not true is if `@today` is `NULL`.

Comment: but why it's always true? I don't get it :S I have declared @today=DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())-2 so when it's Monday @today=0! why never enter in this condition? how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you and I understood good what you intend to do, I would implement this as following. I would define a function that splits your string:

```
create function dbo.SplitString 
(
    @str nvarchar(max), 
    @separator char(1)
)
returns table
AS
return (
with tokens(p, a, b) AS (
    select 
        cast(1 as bigint), 
        cast(1 as bigint), 
        charindex(@separator, @str)
    union all
    select
        p + 1, 
        b + 1, 
        charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)
    from tokens
    where b > 0
)
select
    p-1 ItemIndex,
    substring(
        @str, 
        a, 
        case 
        when b > 0 then b-a 
        ELSE LEN(@str) end) 
    AS Item
from tokens
);

GO
```

And then I would use the following condition:

```
AND where not exists(select * from dbo.SplitString(cfv.value, ',') where    CAST(Item AS INT) > @today )
```

I tested on the sample you gave me and it works. So for the following input:

```
5 
5 
3,4
5 
5 
5 
3,0,1 
3,0 
5 
3
```

It returns:

```
3
3,0,1
3,0
```

Comment: oh perfect, if you see my comment I solved in another way but I think you your is more efficient ;) Thanks so muchhhh